# What is wrong with my UPDATE query with subquery?

Tags: mysql

The following update query is not working, but the select query inside is:

```
UPDATE tb_alunos_detalhes A
SET A.ADTELALUNO = B.TEL
FROM B (
  SELECT ADID ID,
          (CASE
               WHEN `ADTELALUNO` <> '' THEN ( CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ADTELALUNO`, ' ', 1), ' ', -1), ' 9-', SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ADTELALUNO`, ' ', 2), ' ', 10),6,10)))
               ELSE ''
           END) TEL
   FROM tb_alunos_detalhes ) B
WHERE A.ADID = B.ID
```

It gives me the following error:

> Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 62)
>   A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SELECT" at position 67)
>   Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 381)
>   Unexpected token. (near "B" at position 383)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to improve the text in the question and the title. Also removed tags: php and sql, since it is only about MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a `update-join` syntax like

```
UPDATE tb_alunos_detalhes A
JOIN (
  SELECT ID,
          (CASE
               WHEN `ADTELALUNO` <> '' THEN ( CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ADTELALUNO`, ' ', 1), ' ', -1), ' 9-', SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ADTELALUNO`, ' ', 2), ' ', 10),6,10)))
               ELSE ''
           END) TEL
   FROM tb_alunos_detalhes ) B ON A.ADID = B.ID
SET A.ADTELALUNO = B.TEL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use this for reference , and i think this will work for you
UPDATE(
  SELECT Ord.OrderID, Ord.Completed
  FROM Order1 Ord
  WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT *
          FROM Product P
            INNER JOIN Delivery D
              ON Delivery.Delivered = 0 AND P.ProductID = Delivery.DeliveryID
          WHERE Ord.OrderID = P.OrderID
        )
)
SET Completed = 'NO' ;
```

//or without a derived table:

```
UPDATE Order1 Ord
SET Completed = 'NO' 
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM Product P
          INNER JOIN Delivery D
            ON Delivery.Delivered = 0 AND P.ProductID = Delivery.DeliveryID
        WHERE Ord.OrderID = P.OrderID
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE tb_alunos_detalhes A
    SET A.ADTELALUNO = (CASE WHEN `ADTELALUNO` <> ''
                             THEN ( CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ADTELALUNO`, ' ', 1), ' ', -1), ' 9-', SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`ADTELALUNO`, ' ', 2), ' ', 10),6,10)))
                             ELSE ''
                        END);
```

A `JOIN` is not necessary.